# Updating useEffect api call url with user inputs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, use-effect

I'm working on a project, where I need to update a datachart with user inputted dates. I'm having trouble on how to update the url inside the useEffect hook. Here's my relevant code:

```
const finalUrl =`${apiUrl}id=${id}&timing=${time}&start=${finalStart}&end=${finalEnd}`;
    console.log(finalUrl);

useEffect(() => {
    
    axios
      .get<AxiosResponse>(finalUrl, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        setData(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }, []);
  console.log(data);
```

Everything looks good until i get to the axios call. I cannot get useEffect to use the updated url. Logging the response data just gives the same every time. All values inside "finalUrl" are coming from the user.

Comment: Do (some of) the various parts of `finalUrl` come from the end user? Which ones? For instance, I'm assuming `apiUrl` and `id` don't, but the others look like they might...?

Comment: Pass final url as dependent variable inside `useEffect`   like `[finalUrl]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `apiUrl` and `id` never change, but that all the other things you're using in the API URL are inputs from the user.

If so, you need to rebuild the URL in the `useEffect` callback, and make the callback dependent on those user inputs, like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const finalUrl =`${apiUrl}id=${id}&timing=${time}&start=${finalStart}&end=${finalEnd}`;
    axios
        .get<AxiosResponse>(finalUrl, {
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        })
        .then(response => {
            setData(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}, [time, finalStart, finalEnd]);
```

The callback will be called again when `time`, `finalStart`, or `finalEnd` change.

---

Note that you also need to disregard or cancel previous requests when the dependencies change, even if the request hasn't been completed yet. I don't use axios but as I understand it has a "cancel/cancellation token" you can use for doing that. Here's what it would look like with `fetch`, which uses `AbortController`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const finalUrl =`${apiUrl}id=${id}&timing=${time}&start=${finalStart}&end=${finalEnd}`;
    // Create the controller so we can cancel the request
    const controller = new AbortControlller();
    // Pass `signal` to fetch vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    fetch<DataType>(finalUrl, {signal: controller.signal})
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(setData)
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    // Return a cleanup callback
    return () => {
        // Cancel the request since its response would be out of date
        controller.abrt();
    };
}, [time, finalStart, finalEnd]);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Oh my, i knew it was something very simple. Thanks alot! You saved my day.